# How can I properly release a ID3D11ShaderResourceView** to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: c++, directx, release

I have it as a private member of a class.

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView** texture_pool;
```

I set it to NULL in the class constructor like this:

```
texture_pool = NULL;
```

Then I initialize it like this in the class initialization:

```
texture_pool = new ID3D11ShaderResourceView*[texture_count];
for (int n = 0; n < texture_count; n++) texture_pool[n] = NULL;
```

And in the class destructor I release it like this:

```
for (int n = 0; n < texture_count; n++) SAFE_RELEASE(texture_pool[n]);
SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY(texture_pool);
```

But sometimes my program crashes when I exit it and the debbuger point at this line as the cause of the crash:

```
for (int n = 0; n < texture_count; n++) SAFE_RELEASE(texture_pool[n]);
```

If I remove that line everything works smooth, but I'm worried about possible memory leaks if I dont release the array.

So, can I just remove that line and everything will be cleaned up porperly?

These are the defined lines for the release and delete instructions:

```
#define SAFE_RELEASE(p) { if ( (p) ) { (p)->Release(); (p) = 0; } }
#define SAFE_DELETE(a) if( (a) != NULL ) delete (a); (a) = NULL;
#define SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY(a) if( (a) != NULL ) delete[] (a); (a) = NULL;
```

Comment: Have you tried to use your debugger to step into the code to see where at in your destructor's for loop it is crashing? It may be possible that your implementation is written correctly, but you may be trying to release something that is not valid at the time of the destructor's calling.

Comment: I have also noticed something about your Macros, you can refer to the answer below to see if this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown this:

```
#define SAFE_RELEASE(p) { if ( (p) ) { (p)->Release(); (p) = 0; } }
#define SAFE_DELETE(a) if( (a) != NULL ) delete (a); (a) = NULL;
#define SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY(a) if( (a) != NULL ) delete[] (a); (a) = NULL;
```

Try this instead:

```
#ifndef SAFE_RELEASE
    #define SAFE_RELEASE(p) { if(p) { (p)->Release(); (p) = NULL; } }
#endif

#ifndef SAFE_DELETE
     #define SAFE_DELETE(p) { if(p) { delete (p); (p) = nullptr; } }
#endif

#ifndef SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY
    #define SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY(p) { if(p) { delete[](p); (a) = nullptr; } }
#endif
```

When working with macros you need to be careful with your uses of "()" & "{}".

You also do not need (p) != nullptr check since when you have if(p) it will only do the next statement if this check returns true indicating that the pointer is valid and not null.

You are also missing the `#ifndef` and `#endif` around the macro definitions.

If your compiler does not support `nullptr` then you can use `NULL` instead, but `nullptr` is much cleaner and readable.

Comment: @Haalef let me know if this fixes your problem or not so we can go from there to see if you are trying to have DirectX Release an invalid object or not.

Comment: Thanks @Francis Cugler, your code is much cleaner and should avoid possible problems of not using the safeguards #ifndef and #endif. However it didn't fix the problem. The funny thing is that everything works fine when I run both the debug or release versions inside visual studio, but it crashes on exit when I execute the generated .exe file directly in the operating system, What I have done to workaround this issue is that now I use a vector as a container for the array and clean up each element in the destructor as I did before, it seems to have fixed the problem. Works fine everywhere now.

Comment: Good to see that you found a solution that works. That would of been my next suggestion, to use a vector as apposed to an array.